# Stocks, Options, and Income Tax

Tags: united-states, income-tax, options, put-options, covered-call-writing

It is my understanding that if an investor owns a stock and sells a qualified covered call then dividends from the stock are still qualified. However, if an investor owns a stock and buys a put option to protect his position, then any dividends from the stock are qualified.

If an investor owns a stock and sells a qualified covered call against it and then hedges the call position by selling a put on the stock, are the dividends still qualified from the stock? Are there any unexpected tax consequences by selling the put? For example, will the straddle loss limit rule come into effect?

Thanks

Bob

Comment: In the first paragraph you are buying a put, in the second you are selling one. Can you please clarify the question? If you sell a put option it would be for shares you don't own so the dividends would not be relevant as you would not be collecting the dividends for those shares.

Comment: The situation, I am talking about is when you sell both a call and a put plus a long position in the underlying stock.

Comment: If an investor, in the US, owns shares in some stock and hedges the position by buying a put then I claim that any dividends from the stock are not qualified because he as hedged his position and his hedge is not a qualified cover call.

Comment: If you sell a put that does not affect the shares you own, selling a put obligates you to buy shares you don't own yet. That is unrelated to the dividend of the shares that you do own.

Comment: horner150nw you maybe right. However, check out this reasoning. The stock and the short call option is a hedge. The short put option hedges the short call position. The entire position forms a straddle and that straddle is not a qualified covered call. Therefore the dividends are not qualified.

Comment: Do you mean buying a put option as a hedge for the call?  If you sell a call potion you are betting the price will fall. Selling a put is a bet the price will rise. Selling a put option does not hedge a covered call or a long stock position

Comment: I wouldn't consider selling covered call options a hedge either. A hedge is usually to protect against loss. Buying a put option would be a hedge for your long stock position. Selling a covered call will limit your gain, not really protect against loss aside from the premium you collect for the option. Selling coveted calls can be considered an income generating tool

Comment: Selling calls against stock you own is considered a hedge for tax purposes. In addition, for tax purposes, I am fairly sure, that selling puts is a hedge against a naked short call position.

Comment: a naked short position will lose money if the stock price rises.  You could hedge that by purchasing a call with a higher strike price.  Selling a put option will make the most money with an increase in price however, your gain is limited to what you sold the option for.  Your potential loss on the naked call is theoretically unlimited where your gain on the put is limited, I don't know that I would consider that a very effective hedge.

Comment: Would selling calls against stock you own be a good hedge for tax purposes?  When you sell the calls you are paying short term capital gains where the stock might be long term gains depending on how long you have held it.  If you are able to sell multiple calls over the time you hold the stock without getting exercised they could be a hedge against loss or could be a source of income but depending on what price your call gets exercised at and what the price of the stock is at that time you could also be missing out on some gains.  Like anything else in the market, it's a gamble.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the stock can have "qualified dividends", which would normally be the case if the stock was listed in the US and you were able to trade options on it, and held them for 60 days period prior to the dividend being paid.

The options themselves are separate securities from the stock and do not pay, nor entitle you to dividends.  The money received from or used to pay for the options would be treated as income from short term purchase and sales of securities (if less than 1 year).  Long term, if the opening and closing of the positions was more than 1 year  (or 60/40 if the options were on equity index futures rather than stocks).

Comment: Qual-div holding period (of 60 days) can be _before and/or after_ ex-div date, which is effectively when you get the _right_ to the dividend; record date is (now) 2 days later, and actual payment is usually a week or two after record but sometimes more.